# Outputting an array each iteration of a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a script which takes number inputs from user, assigns them to an array, then uses the bubble sort method to put these numbers in order.

Everything is working great, but I can't seem to figure out how to output the contents of the array AS it is being changed each iteration. Basically, I want to watch it in action on a **new line** for each outer for() loop cycle.

```js
function sortFunction()
{
var totalNums = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter?","");
var numsArray = [];

  for(i=0; i<totalNums; ++i)
  {

        var nums = prompt("Please enter number " ,"");
        if(nums != 'x')
        {
        numsArray[i] = parseInt(nums);
        document.getElementById("unsorted").innerHTML = "Orignal Numbers: " + numsArray;

      }
  }

var length = numsArray.length;
var swapped;

  do
  {
  swapped = false;
      for (var j=0; j < length-1; j++)
      {
          if (numsArray[j] > numsArray[j+1])
          {
          var temp = numsArray[j];
          numsArray[j] = numsArray[j+1];
          numsArray[j+1] = temp;
          swapped = true;

          }
      }
      document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = (numsArray); //This is where I am needing help
  } while (swapped);
}
```

```html
<p> Click the button to enter and display an array of numbers! </p>
<button onclick="sortFunction()">Click Me</button>

<div id ="unsorted">Unsorted</div>
<div id ="sorted">Sorted</div>
```

Comment: where u  output the contents of the array AS it is being changed each iteration?

Comment: document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = (numsArray); but I realize that is just overwriting what is there each time instead of displaying it on a new line

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want, but have you tried `innerHTML += something`, or storing the intermediate stages in an array of arrays?

Comment: @Tman If you like to highlight exact changes in each iteration please see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. All I did was change the operator on the innerHTML line to `+=` instead of `=`. I also added a line to clear out the "sorted" queue each time, and some formatting for the results.

```js
function sortFunction() {
  var totalNums = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter?", "");
  var numsArray = [];
 
  document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = "";
  
  for (i = 0; i < totalNums; ++i) {

    var nums = prompt("Please enter number ", "");
    if (nums != 'x') {
      numsArray[i] = parseInt(nums);
      document.getElementById("unsorted").innerHTML = "Orignal Numbers: " + numsArray;

    }
  }

  var length = numsArray.length;
  var swapped;
  let x = 0;

  do {
    x++;
    swapped = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < length - 1; j++) {
      if (numsArray[j] > numsArray[j + 1]) {
        var temp = numsArray[j];
        numsArray[j] = numsArray[j + 1];
        numsArray[j + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;

      }
    }
    document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML += "Step " + x + ": " + (numsArray) + "<br>"; //This is where I am needing help
  } while (swapped);
}
```

```html
<p> Click the button to enter and display an array of numbers! </p>
<button onclick="sortFunction()">Click Me</button>
<div id="unsorted">Unsorted</div>
<div id="sorted">Sorted</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually used a combination of two different answers here since both of them by themselves didn't seem to give the desired effect.

This ended up working: 

`document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML += "<div>" + "Iteration " + count  + " - " + numsArray + "</div>";`

Answer (score 1):

Add

`document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML += "<div>" + numsArray[i] + </div>;`

within the brackets of your for-loop

Answer (score 1):

I added some code so you can highlight changes in each iteration

```js
function sortFunction()
{
   var totalNums = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter?","");
   var numsArray = [];

  for(i=0; i<totalNums; ++i)
  {

      var nums = prompt("Please enter number " ,"");
      if(nums != 'x')
      {
          numsArray[i] = parseInt(nums);
          document.getElementById("unsorted").innerHTML = "Orignal Numbers: " + numsArray;
      }
  }

  var length = numsArray.length;
  var swapped;
  let sortingProcessRecorder = '';
  let counter = 1;

  do
  {
      swapped = false;
      for (var j=0; j < length-1; j++)
      {
          if (numsArray[j] > numsArray[j+1])
          {
            var temp = numsArray[j];
            numsArray[j] = '<span style=\"color:red;\">' + numsArray[j+1] + '</span>';
            numsArray[j+1] = '<span style=\"color:red;\">' + temp + '</span>';
            swapped = true;
          }
          sortingProcessRecorder += '<b>' + counter++ + ': </b>' + numsArray + '<br />';
          numsArray[j] = stripHtml(numsArray[j])
          numsArray[j + 1] = stripHtml(numsArray[j + 1])
      }
  } while (swapped);

  document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = 'Sorting Process: <br />' + sortingProcessRecorder;

}

function stripHtml(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

```html
<p> Click the button to enter and display an array of numbers! </p>
<button onclick="sortFunction()">Click Me</button>
<div id ="unsorted">Unsorted</div>
<div id ="sorted">Sorted</div>
```